# Need to display multi-select menu component with limited space

Tags: interaction-design, multi-selection, space-constraints

I am looking for a solution to display a multi-select option. Currently, we have a drop-down menu, but that is not very intuitive if user has to make multiple selections.

Any suggestions on how to convert this drop-down to a mechanism that supports multi selections, while taking into consideration space limitations. The menu bars I am looking to change are "Filter by Department" and "Filter by Discipline".

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) by the folks who made Harvest Time Tracking?
There's a great multiselect tool, with keyboard support.

In terms of space, if your design is responsive (is that your intention?), you'll run out of horizontal space.

Chose will allow you to stack your choices vertically, so you'll lose some vertical space, depending on how many departments or disciplines a user chooses. It's still a win. See below screenshot from Chosen's [description](http://www.getharvest.com/blog/2011/07/chosen-plug-in/):

[image]

Without knowing your business requirements or case studies, I would give this a shot from the info you've given us.